# isRoot() in DefaultMutableTreeNode

Tags: java, tree, root, jtree, defaultmutabletreenode

Why there is an isRoot() function in DefaultMutableTreeNode? I ask because I have a Class that extends DefaultMutableTreeNode. I would like to be able to use a single instance of this class in multiple different JTree objects. However, it would seem that isRoot() is a question I should be asking the tree object itself. Can anyone provide any insight as to why this function exists at a node level instead of the tree level?

Comment: It has to exist at Node Level because is explicitly checking if that node is the root or not. Instead of relying on an external method where you have to pass a Node as an argument to decide if is the root or not.

Comment: Well, to further my question, what happens when the Node is NOT a root in one tree, but is a root in a different tree?

Comment: Then you've successfully made a programming bug by sharing a node in two separate trees.

Comment: What you want to share is the DATA in a Node not the Node structure itself. Let each Tree Handle its own Node structure

Comment: If the same node is in two different trees are different levels,  its `getParent()` method can't possibly return a correct value.

Comment: I see. Well, I think I know what I should do now. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

The tree object can't be the root of the tree; the JTree object isn't a node.

DefaultMutableTreeNode is designed to facilitate recursive traversal of the tree. Since a recursive method processing the tree will only have access to one node (and its subsequent nodes) at a time, the only way for the method to distinguish the root of the tree is for the nodes to inidivdually keep track of whether or not they are the root of the tree.